# How to define custom drawable in xml and use its custom attributes

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-custom-drawable

Aim :

1. I have `MyDrawable` which extends to `GradientDrawable`.
2. I have defined custom attribute for `MyDrawable`.
3. I have created xml in `res->drawable->test_drawable.xml` which has my `<drawable>` resource.
4. I am using custom defined attribute from step 2 in `test_drawable.xml` to pass values to `MyDrawable`.
5. **Use custom attributes passed from `test_drawable.xml` in `MyDrawable.inflate()` *this part is not working***

Problem :

In `MyDrawable.inflate()` I am not getting my custom attribute values defined in `res->drawable->test_drawable.xml`

MyDrawable:

```
class MyDrawable() : GradientDrawable() {
private var radiusPercentage : Int = 25

  override fun inflate(
    r: Resources,
    parser: XmlPullParser,
    attrs: AttributeSet,
    theme: Resources.Theme?
  ) {
super.inflate(r, parser, attrs, theme)
val a = r.obtainAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyDrawable)
// I am always getting 0 here. Checked with breakpoint in debug mode.
val radius = a.getInteger(R.styleable.MyDrawable_radiusPercentage, 0)
radiusPercentage = radius
}
}
```

Custom attribute:

```
<declare-styleable name="MyDrawable">
    <attr name="radiusPercentage" format="integer"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

res->drawable->test_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<drawable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    class="com.test.app.RoundedCornersDrawable
    app:radiusPercentage="50" />
```

I am setting it on my container

```
binding.container.background =
      AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.test_drawable)
```

Comment: Try looking at [Custom View Example With Custom Drawable/Parameters(Kotlin)](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/custom-view-drawable-attributes).